# How to align a twitter bootstrap form of class well in the center of a page?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center my form of class well in the middle of the screen , could someone tell me how to modify this code to do so ?

```
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
        <img  class="myimg" src="img/logo.png" alt="my logo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="well span4">
            <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Username"/><br/>
            <input type="password" class="span3" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary span3">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<div class="container text-center">
```

on the second `.container` that you have right there (the parent of the `.well`).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Just offset your form by 4. This works because the 3 cols are of equal width

```
<div class="container">
<div class="container">
    <img  class="myimg" src="img/logo.png" alt="my logo"/>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <form class="well offset4 span4">
        <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Username"/><br/>
        <input type="password" class="span3" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary span3">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: but if I want to keep responsiveness, wouldn t that ruin the thing ?